# Could not get drawing cache of a webview: android

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

I have a webview. I want to get its drawing cache and and save it as a file in sdcard. I used following code:

```
WebView wv=new WebView(this);
wv.loadData(rawHtml,"text/html",null); // rawHtml is my html code
wv.buildDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp=wv.getDrawingCache();
```

Dont know why `wv.getDrawingCache()` always returns `null`.
I have tested my html code using:

```
setContentView(wv);
```

Its displaying properly.

Comment: Handle the webviewCLient's onPageFinish() method and write this code in that to get the drawing cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using this method immediately in the `onCreate()?` If yes then you might have to consider overriding the below method,

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Bitmap bmp=wv.getDrawingCache();
}
```

This method gets called as soon as your view gets drawn. And this is where you will get a view at all.

Comment: I dont want webview to set to my activity. I just tested it with setContentView() to know whether html part is correct or not. It was displaying properly.

Comment: I just want an image bitmap of that webview